# Vectorizing string formatting across NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two integer arrays that I want to combine, per element, into a single array of strings of the form `'a[i]_b[i]'`. That is, I have

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
```

and I want to obtain the array

```
result = np.array(['1_4', '2_5', '3_6'])
```

I can easily do this with a list comprehension:

```
result = np.array(['{}_{}'.format(a[i], b[i]) for i in range(len(a))])
```

But my arrays `a` and `b` are very long, and this is too slow. Is there a way to do this through numpy calls? Something that is `hstack`-ish? I can get this far:

```
result np.hstack([a.resahpe(len(a), 1), b.reshape(len(b), 1)])
```

which gives me

```
np.array([[1, 4]
          [2, 5]
          [3, 6]])
```

Surely there must be a simple way to get from here to my desired result...

**Edit:**

Using two calls of `defchararray` seems to be even slower than a list comprehension, but `frompyfunc` is effective...

```
>>> import timeit
>>> t = Timer("""['{}_{}'.format(a[i], b[i]) for i in range(len(b))]""", setup="""import numpy as np; a = np.random.randn(10000); b=np.random.randn(10000)""")
>>> t.timeit(1000)
22.310123541974463

>>> t2 = Timer("""np.core.defchararray.add(np.core.defchararray.add(a.astype(str),'_'), b.astype(str))""", setup="""import numpy as np; a = np.random.randn(10000); b=np.random.randn(10000)""")
>>> t2.timeit(1000)
28.489826270961203

>>> t3 = Timer("""fv(a,b)""", setup='import numpy as np; a = np.random.randn(10000); b=np.random.randn(10000); fv =  np.frompyfunc("{}_{}".format, 2, 1)')
>>> t3.timeit(1000)
15.455791965010576
```

And here it is as a function of the length of `a` and `b` (seems stable):

[image]

Comment: `numpy` is not really designed for dealing with strings efficiently that is why it is called *num*py

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's designed to provide optimized vector/matrix operations in general

Comment: No, *not in general*. Specifically, it is not going to be very efficient with dtype=object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've definitely had plenty of experience that would suggest otherwise. I realize that it's not going to be order of magnitude improvements that you'd see with `float` or `int` operations. But it's still some return. See my edits.

Comment: Well, my own experience is the opposite. The problem with your examples is that you are *still using numpy arrays in your list comprehension*. Iterating over numpy arrays is slow, it requires re-creating a Python object on each iteration. You should convert to lists, or *start* with lists. Note the following tests: https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/b6509486c9333db11b0eac78e7bc297c Notice, that when you start with lists, you do *better* with a list comprehension that using arrays with from_func.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fv = np.frompyfunc("{}_{}".format, 2, 1)
result = fv(a, b)  # array(['1_4', '2_5', '3_6'], dtype=object)
```

Based on some timing this has roughly 1/3 the run time of list comprehension and conversion to np.array.

```
In [2]: a = np.arange(100000)

In [3]: b = np.arange(100000) + a.size

In [4]: fv = np.frompyfunc("{}_{}".format, 2, 1)

In [5]: def f(a, b): return np.array(["{}_{}".format(a,b) for a,b in zip(a,b)], dtype=object)

In [6]: %timeit f(a,b)
370 ms ± 12.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [7]: %timeit fv(a,b)
137 ms ± 1.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [defchararray.add](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.add.html)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
c = np.core.defchararray.add(a.astype(str),'_')
c = np.core.defchararray.add(c,b.astype(str))
print(c) #['1_4' '2_5' '3_6']
```